# Perform a single task on (220 choose 5) combination in a dataframe

Tags: python, simulation

I have data with 220 rows. Initially choose 5 rows randomly and apply an operation to them. Now I have to perform a similar task on (220 choose 5) combination(That means 4102565544 data frames with 5 rows).Python is hitting memory issues when I use `list(itertools.combinations(list(range(0,222)),5))` and applying loop on each data frame with 5 rows is too much time-consuming. Below I have attached my data as a dictionary and I have replicated my problem set.

Data

```
df={'Name': {0: '004737367A89', 1: '006D631822DA', 2: '007FEEEF095D', 3: '015EA8035B5D', 4: '0168C7824FB3', 5: '02236A01C769', 6: '026A35601C28', 7: '03939D273F7D', 8: '05BE3A6A6344', 9: '0735B7F399C8', 10: '075F90DEDAAC', 11: '079D00DB87B6', 12: '08321FDDA475', 13: '084147D3DE00', 14: '08693ADAF466', 15: '08EE69FF7C9B', 16: '0996F835D14B', 17: '0A061E004649', 18: '0BDADD43DF2D', 19: '0D580A803B2C', 20: '11DCF10E0F76', 21: '1241EC5AC73C', 22: '150595F71A7A', 23: '160D7B436114', 24: '1805135DA1B7', 25: '18D26316EA11', 26: '1B744908A7E9', 27: '1CB417508187', 28: '1EA75E92E370', 29: '1F1B4DA40CE4', 30: '209D86760A9C', 31: '228BC53DB280', 32: '235D0F9A5E0E', 33: '2452814BCC90', 34: '2923CA6C88B1', 35: '2CB60EF30BAA', 36: '2CD7BD1FC443', 37: '2D03FAC79D60', 38: '2F34FFA27A7C', 39: '2F8F282FDCEE', 40: '3.03891E+11', 41: '31B4A8BDBA5F', 42: '34EC4E7D8E15', 43: '3695444ADBFF', 44: '370F1D138305', 45: '3826943C86AF', 46: '39F11738A59D', 47: '39F2FF0A2E05', 48: '3A8B6F61E548', 49: '3B256CE48F60', 50: '3C09C2C73655', 51: '3D6858B43366', 52: '3D94154B544C', 53: '3DDD62DDF6C4', 54: '3EBDAFB8E7EE', 55: '408B3D0EAF85', 56: '40ED913F4BB6', 57: '43380E855E4E', 58: '44C8332521DE', 59: '4817047FFAC1', 60: '481896BC4240', 61: '49263E82B2B8', 62: '4AF76F8D6BBB', 63: '4BC2016E5222', 64: '4CCF2D4FF5EC', 65: '4E9750936994', 66: '4F61F6A5588D', 67: '505F16F25595', 68: '50756E6D3B32', 69: '50E1E1F5F31D', 70: '516B4C9C3F45', 71: '52608C24A09E', 72: '52B2EBC622A6', 73: '539B8164BD32', 74: '5462E581A288', 75: '55149C502434', 76: '55D8B9306A65', 77: '5808368AFA0A', 78: '58F6BA305E2A', 79: '58FE73C690DA', 80: '596857EDC73F', 81: '599DF7F0CB41', 82: '59F1F27E85F4', 83: '5AE11428142F', 84: '5B27B574EA5B', 85: '5D3FA98DDD61', 86: '5DE6CFC7E471', 87: '5DF85F5EA21C', 88: '5EA87B759595', 89: '5EAA2E0BEAA2', 90: '5EAFEBA99A30', 91: '5EFC03FC84DF', 92: '5F6A8D18E234', 93: '6008B6021BAA', 94: '63765F49AC32', 95: '64099F419232', 96: '652349DF5059', 97: '6551FB43EE37', 98: '6613C12B0634', 99: '66C312BFDFD6', 100: '66D964D2E1D0', 101: '6790A35547E2', 102: '67A2603888E5', 103: '6991A9411704', 104: '6CFC28C22836', 105: '6D5DAED137C9', 106: '6EBB87FAD022', 107: '6EF1206450AF', 108: '70C74C90C3E2', 109: '71168B36CCFD', 110: '7177392ADD8B', 111: '74AF6AA78FB9', 112: '759CFBB05E2F', 113: '771E8EA5A4C7', 114: '7740740D57BE', 115: '7926DFB85C8B', 116: '7A6091203844', 117: '7C23D53CE5DD', 118: '7C4ED1AA239F', 119: '7E0C21E0010F', 120: '80E9914A0BF8', 121: '82867FEAF519', 122: '82C735B34C85', 123: '85EF1FFBAC47', 124: '872F22A4D018', 125: '87C72000AAB2', 126: '8978B70E88C3', 127: '8ADEF3F17E42', 128: '8B5F4EE22DF5', 129: '8B757ED14D67', 130: '8E0C10341AA8', 131: '90289E4E68F6', 132: '9259DEED6524', 133: '92754763710B', 134: '92B164934E01', 135: '96DBA1873BFF', 136: '97E7144ECEF9', 137: '9AE4EB9DF4F0', 138: '9CAC53908EE1', 139: '9F31161E7BDF', 140: 'A090B8A939CB', 141: 'A12E89E87CB5', 142: 'A31CA572620F', 143: 'A4263AA51F9A', 144: 'A540D6615FA0', 145: 'A56804CE6BAF', 146: 'A60313C4FC06', 147: 'A612803F81BA', 148: 'A77E12FFA171', 149: 'A87B6602E946', 150: 'AADE28D99973', 151: 'AEB37BE9DBFF', 152: 'B04ACAB6A193', 153: 'B41004303288', 154: 'B454AAFDA2AF', 155: 'B701B4E2F2BF', 156: 'B7EF621EC0AE', 157: 'B9084B8E2378', 158: 'BA8C4B0E8378', 159: 'BBD01B2776A8', 160: 'BE5377A632DF', 161: 'BE8D95B26DEE', 162: 'BEEB25AC3BB3', 163: 'BF585F42B5F6', 164: 'BF889C615B6A', 165: 'C1934D47BC69', 166: 'C31934680839', 167: 'C43F40D3D865', 168: 'C4955BCC1F0C', 169: 'C4F03F22DE3E', 170: 'C5BC9B26046C', 171: 'C5D2BE738C56', 172: 'C762399CAF83', 173: 'C7B9B444D117', 174: 'C943B9F6FDDF', 175: 'C9C7138CAF65', 176: 'CB66BE597E30', 177: 'CC7DA44E344E', 178: 'CE81A7E65B6B', 179: 'CE971F87D0B5', 180: 'CECC8C16ECAB', 181: 'D111860A3AC1', 182: 'D159C02757AE', 183: 'D33BB70DCA77', 184: 'D386F0671D80', 185: 'D43B801CCCA9', 186: 'D465BE3D4A94', 187: 'D49E08EEC650', 188: 'D4BD5D5DD7E4', 189: 'D64F455CB56A', 190: 'D6D99F00B58B', 191: 'D7774555E609', 192: 'D7CDFD417C01', 193: 'DBF16B9938A4', 194: 'DCC2FA798C09', 195: 'DE6E090827B8', 196: 'E25F5A55A4D8', 197: 'E5A82C4E86C7', 198: 'E5AC30A8337B', 199: 'E6EBC0EFBF18', 200: 'EB9BBBA2FEB9', 201: 'EC8A20CAC153', 202: 'EC8EA44FDACD', 203: 'ECB284CBDDA7', 204: 'EED0F8B3B968', 205: 'EF4B578B0902', 206: 'F13986786A7A', 207: 'F17F0E81FC73', 208: 'F34CFBCB7A28', 209: 'F396C1E8BF59', 210: 'F40ED923507F', 211: 'F87A72CF9671', 212: 'F8CDE15A2FCB', 213: 'F9032EE897A9', 214: 'FAC08B5AA521', 215: 'FB3071FBA3BC', 216: 'FC6435726337', 217: 'FD5F2F4D32D7', 218: 'FD6E925243AA', 219: 'FDA85734568D', 220: 'FF18E7D41654', 221: 'FFEC03758A05'}, 'Code': {0: 375000, 1: 275000, 2: 225000, 3: 275000, 4: 175000, 5: 275000, 6: 295000, 7: 525000, 8: 175000, 9: 135000, 10: 275000, 11: 250000, 12: 275000, 13: 350000, 14: 225000, 15: 175000, 16: 395000, 17: 275000, 18: 225000, 19: 195000, 20: 225000, 21: 175000, 22: 135000, 23: 225000, 24: 250000, 25: 225000, 26: 250000, 27: 295000, 28: 275000, 29: 250000, 30: 275000, 31: 250000, 32: 295000, 33: 195000, 34: 275000, 35: 195000, 36: 275000, 37: 175000, 38: 525000, 39: 225000, 40: 350000, 41: 135000, 42: 295000, 43: 195000, 44: 495000, 45: 495000, 46: 275000, 47: 375000, 48: 295000, 49: 250000, 50: 250000, 51: 225000, 52: 175000, 53: 250000, 54: 475000, 55: 135000, 56: 350000, 57: 225000, 58: 250000, 59: 275000, 60: 225000, 61: 295000, 62: 225000, 63: 250000, 64: 225000, 65: 250000, 66: 135000, 67: 175000, 68: 295000, 69: 175000, 70: 295000, 71: 295000, 72: 225000, 73: 225000, 74: 365000, 75: 295000, 76: 225000, 77: 195000, 78: 225000, 79: 225000, 80: 225000, 81: 295000, 82: 135000, 83: 195000, 84: 295000, 85: 550000, 86: 250000, 87: 225000, 88: 275000, 89: 225000, 90: 295000, 91: 250000, 92: 250000, 93: 225000, 94: 175000, 95: 250000, 96: 175000, 97: 350000, 98: 175000, 99: 275000, 100: 295000, 101: 225000, 102: 225000, 103: 195000, 104: 175000, 105: 350000, 106: 175000, 107: 275000, 108: 275000, 109: 175000, 110: 195000, 111: 225000, 112: 275000, 113: 375000, 114: 135000, 115: 135000, 116: 395000, 117: 295000, 118: 195000, 119: 275000, 120: 195000, 121: 375000, 122: 195000, 123: 275000, 124: 275000, 125: 175000, 126: 325000, 127: 275000, 128: 250000, 129: 135000, 130: 175000, 131: 195000, 132: 550000, 133: 225000, 134: 250000, 135: 350000, 136: 495000, 137: 275000, 138: 135000, 139: 175000, 140: 175000, 141: 225000, 142: 175000, 143: 275000, 144: 325000, 145: 295000, 146: 275000, 147: 275000, 148: 175000, 149: 350000, 150: 550000, 151: 250000, 152: 350000, 153: 325000, 154: 175000, 155: 250000, 156: 175000, 157: 250000, 158: 275000, 159: 225000, 160: 195000, 161: 175000, 162: 225000, 163: 275000, 164: 225000, 165: 135000, 166: 250000, 167: 225000, 168: 175000, 169: 275000, 170: 175000, 171: 275000, 172: 175000, 173: 195000, 174: 325000, 175: 275000, 176: 295000, 177: 350000, 178: 350000, 179: 425000, 180: 225000, 181: 135000, 182: 150000, 183: 135000, 184: 350000, 185: 225000, 186: 375000, 187: 175000, 188: 295000, 189: 195000, 190: 350000, 191: 175000, 192: 225000, 193: 195000, 194: 195000, 195: 350000, 196: 250000, 197: 175000, 198: 175000, 199: 395000, 200: 175000, 201: 225000, 202: 175000, 203: 350000, 204: 175000, 205: 250000, 206: 375000, 207: 275000, 208: 525000, 209: 175000, 210: 375000, 211: 295000, 212: 275000, 213: 175000, 214: 325000, 215: 250000, 216: 195000, 217: 275000, 218: 250000, 219: 135000, 220: 195000, 221: 135000}}
```

What I want is to select random 5 rows first

```
import random
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
inputt=pd.DataFrame({"NameID":data1.Name[random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)]})
for i in range(len(inputt.index)):
      D1 = data[data["Name"] == inputt["NameID"].iloc[i]]
      D2 =  D2.append(D1)

values=D2.Code       
real_sum=values.sum()
```

and then I want to perform the same operation on the rest of the rows in the data frame and figure which data frame with such rows has sum less than the real_sum.Is there any simulation technique I can apply here  or anything else ?

Thanks

Comment: I have attached another question liked to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570794/calculating-combinations-from-a-list-given-that-atleast-one-location-is-selected)

Comment: Do you actually need to know which sets of rows have a smaller sum or just something like what percentage?

Comment: @KyleParsons I want rows that have a sum greater than the user's selected sum. Say the user chooses 5 random rows and their sum is 64 I want to find out that combination of rows that have a sum greater than 64.

Comment: Btw, to get 5 random rows, you can use `df.sample(5)`

Comment: If you need to keep all of these sets of rows in memory, you're likely to have memory issues.  If your selecting half of the sets that's 2B sets of rows.

Comment: @Sylvain what are the chances that all the rows will be covered in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the memory issues you don't need to access the whole information directly. What I mean is that you can be "lazy" about it and use it only when needed. -> Enter Lazy evaluation

> In programming language theory, lazy evaluation, or call-by-need,[1] is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

This means that you don't need to evaluate the result from the combinations completely at first, but only when needed:

```
import itertools 

# This will create an iterator (not the whole list)
combos = itertools.combinations(list(range(0,222)),5)
```

and use it afterwards like this:

```
D2 = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.DataFrame(df)

for combo in combos:
    inputt=pd.DataFrame({"NameID":data.Name[list(combo)]})

    for i in range(len(inputt.index)):
        D1 = data[data["Name"] == inputt["NameID"].iloc[i]]
        D2 =  D2.append(D1)

    values=D2.Code       
    real_sum=values.sum()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing right now buts It's still time-consuming.I can remove cases that I don't want which I am not able to. I am trying to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570794/calculating-combinations-from-a-list-given-that-atleast-one-location-is-selected). Its related to this question. Could you please look it at ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. You stated, that you have memory issues, which is normal if you evaluate the whole iterator at once. Do you want to make it also faster?

Comment: Yes it can be improved alot but i am not sure how.

Comment: is your goal to compute the D2 DataFrame?

Comment: My goal is to find all the data frames which have sum larger than sum of rows of data frame what user has selected and store them in a list. Please see attached link in my first comment

Comment: You have the typical trade-off memory vs run time here. You can `pass` cases that you don't need to compute. Or you can have a list/hash of cases that you don't need to compute, that you update at each iteration ?