# Calculating combinations from a list given that atleast one location is selected

Tags: python, combinations

I have a vector "vec" of sub-locations. The parent locations are (Town Ext, Chowk,Town Market)

```
   Parent_Location_Name Sub_Location_Name
0              Town Ext        Town Ext_1
1              Town Ext        Town Ext_2
2              Town Ext        Town Ext_3
3           Town Market     Town Market_1
4           Town Market     Town Market_2
5           Town Market     Town Market_3
6           Town Market     Town Market_4
7           Town Market     Town Market_5
8                 Chowk           Chowk_1
9                 Chowk           Chowk_2
10                Chowk           Chowk_3
11                Chowk           Chowk_4

vec=['Town Ext_1','Town Ext_2','Town Ext_3','Town Market_1','Town Market_2','Town Market_3','Town Market_4','Town Market_5','Chowk_1','Chowk_2','Chowk_3','Chowk_4']
vec
['Town Ext_1',
 'Town Ext_2',
 'Town Ext_3',
 'Town Market_1',
 'Town Market_2',
 'Town Market_3',
 'Town Market_4',
 'Town Market_5',
 'Chowk_1',
 'Chowk_2',
 'Chowk_3',
 'Chowk_4']
```

When i apply `list(combinations(vec,4)` it gives all the combinations but what I want is that each location must be selected once. The combination shouldn't involve  ('Town Market_4', 'Chowk_1', 'Chowk_2', 'Chowk_3') because sub-location chowk has been selected thrice and we have excluded Town Ext  Parent location totally. It should be ('Town Market_4', ''Town Ext_1'', 'Chowk_2', 'Chowk_3') or
('Town Market_4', ''Town Ext_1'', 'Chowk_2', 'Town Ext_2') etc. I have to involve all the parent locations atleast once.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have replicated my problem set here. My code involves different vectors different names.

Comment: I don't understand how these conditions are defined, e.g. "we have excluded Town Ext Parent location totally" => where? Please describe more clearly.

Comment: @mcsoini If apply itertools::combinations(vec,4) it gives all possible combinations of rows which I don't want. I want those combinations in which at least one sublocation from the parent location is chosen. from "we have excluded Town Ext Parent location totally" I meant that we have not even taken one sub location from Town Ext but we must include atleast one sub location under each parent location in combination of rows.